# How to set xhtml panel toggle by default?

Tags: primefaces, xhtml

I want to set the standard toggle of a panel like this:

```
<p:panel id="horizontal" header="Advanced Settings" toggleable="true"  toggleOrientation="horizontal">

</p:panel>
```

So that when you first open the page you see the panel like this: [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b2SG.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the [collapsed](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/panel?id=attributes) attribute:

```
<p:panel id="horizontal" header="Advanced Settings" toggleable="true"  toggleOrientation="horizontal"
  collapsed="true">

</p:panel>
```